# Placing database data in multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, multidimensional-array

For my webshop, I have 1 database with 3 relevant tables.
In order to display the data, I was advised to place the data out of these databases in 3 two dimensional arrays so that I could visualize what I was doing.
However, my only successful attempt of placing the data in the array resulted in the code overwriting itself, only showing the last data in the table.

**Can anyone give me some suggestions on how to set up my array in a way that its automatically filled?**

```
<?php
        //Create the Multiarrays. 2D, one per table.

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        //Open the database
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM productwindow";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        //Multiarray locatie 1. When the array starts here, the browser chokes.
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                //multiarray locatie 2. When the array starts here, the browser also chokes.
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                    $product = array( //multiarray locatie 3. The problem is that the array seems to overwrite itself.
                        array(  //I want PHP to repeat this bit of code for every product in my database, so that I can use it later on.
                            "ID" => $row["ID"],
                            "Name" => $row["Productname"],
                            "Price" => $row["Pricetag"],
                            "Supply" => $row["Productsupply"],
                            "Tags" => $row["Tags"],
                            "Materials" => $row["Materials"],
                        ),
                    );
                }
                //Multiarray locatie 2 end woul be placed here
            } else {
                echo "0 results found. Please check database connection.";
            }
        //Multiarray locatie 1 end woul be placed here. 

        $conn->close();
        //      
        echo "<br/>";
        $searchby = "Pluimstaart";//The keyword that I used in earlier concepts to filter on specific products. I now need a for loop to procedurally run through the multiarray.
        $array_subjected_to_search = $product;
        $key = array_search($searchby, array_column($array_subjected_to_search, "Name")); //If it cannot be done via a foreloop, I would need an alternative to "array_search" to show the contents of my array.
        var_dump($array_subjected_to_search[$key]);//Used to see if I actually fill my array with data. It only shows the latest data.

        //From here on out I build the website like follows;
        echo "<br/>product data: " . $product[$key["Supply"]] . ".";
    ?>
```

Thank you very much for your feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$product` variable is being overwritten on each loop because you are making it equal a brand new array each time:

```
$product = array(...
```

Instead you should be appending elements to the end of an array, using either [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php), or this shorthand:

```
$product[] = [
    "ID" => $row["ID"],
    "Name" => $row["Productname"],
    "Price" => $row["Pricetag"],
    "Supply" => $row["Productsupply"],
    "Tags" => $row["Tags"],
    "Materials" => $row["Materials"]
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace your code of if else code by this code and try

```
      $product[]=array();
      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {                
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $product[]["ID"]=$row["ID"];
                $product[]["Name"]=$row["Productname"];
                $product[]["Price"]=$row["Price"];
                $product[]["Supply"]=$row["Supply"];
                $product[]["Tags"]=$row["Tags"];
                $product[]["Materials"]=$row["Materials"];                    
            }

        } else {
            echo "0 results found. Please check database connection.";
        }
```

Comment: This is the first time ive seen a multidimensional array declared like this. It provides a clean insight of how it works, thank you Bhaskar!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you meant...

```
$i = 0; 
$product = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

   $product[$i] = array(

    "ID" => $row["ID"],
    "Name" => $row["Productname"],
    "Price" => $row["Pricetag"],
    "Supply" => $row["Productsupply"],
    "Tags" => $row["Tags"],
    "Materials" => $row["Materials"],

  );
$i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Dieter, the code provided by Gary is a bit more elegant but this seems to work as well.